# Unable to extract value using getAttribute in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to extract the value of an attribute using getAttribute in selenium what is the alternative, does any one know? 
If you do know please share. I cannot share the website, since you can access that website only within the organisation, so no point in sharing a private website. value is like this **value=Sales909039032.**

I used findElement.getAttribute('value') but unable to grab the value. it works fine on the other page of the same website, but doesn't work on this particular page. Is this an isolated issue with the website, like a technical error or website developers mistake which is causing the error?

Comment: What is the result? Some exception or null?

Comment: yes, result is a null string i.e blank, no output. No i didn't encounter any exception just a  null string..Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I use Javascript to get `value` attribute. Maybe this will work for you.

```
public String getValue(WebElement element) {
        return (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].value", element);
    }
```